# How to make a method with a return statement that is inside an abstract class which implements an interface get inherited by a subclass?

Tags: java

I will post the part of the code that I have trouble with. I scoured the internet for hours and cannot find a solution to how to properly solve this problem with a method that has a return and isn't just a sentence. I would seriously appreciate any help that I can get! Essentially what I need is for my subclass to inherit the same method in its abstract father without any changes, so that I can apply that in my main code.

public class Main {

```
interface Dodela
{
public int PovecajKS();
public int SmanjiS();
}

public static abstract class Ekspanzija implements Dodela
{
    
final public int PovecajKS(int a, int b)
{
a = a + b;
return a;
}
final public int SmanjiS(int a, int b)
{
a = a - b;
return a;
}
}

public static class EkspanzijaP extends Ekspanzija implements Dodela
{

    public int PovecajKS()
    {
    }

    public int SmanjiS() {
        int a = 0, b = 0;
        a = a - b;
        return a;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier to understand if you: a) used top-level classes (no static modifier); b) used English names (given that the rest of the question is in English, as is this site); c) followed Java naming conventions; d) formatted your code with conventional indentation etc. The easier you make it for people to help you, the more likely you are to receive that help.

Comment: (It's really unclear to me what you're trying to do, here. You *do* inherit methods, but the parameterized methods can't be used to implement the parameterless methods from the interface...)

Answer (score 0):

It already inherits all methods of its father, to use the method inside the subclass, it can be called like this

> super.`yourFunctionName()`

Comment: I cannot do that, It asks me to override the two methods. Which I don't want to